# How do you write the lines from #2 into a file called output.txt?

Tags: shell, ubuntu

How do you write the lines from #2 into a file called output.txt?

Answer (score 0):

Use `tail` command:

```
tail +2 input.txt > output.txt
```

or

```
sed '1d' input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: `tail +2` - did you miss the space after `tail`?

Comment: how to output from a specific line from  a shell display to another file?

Comment: There is no such thing as "shell display". Please give an example of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @codeforester, why not to use sed command, because tail can not read +2?what i want now is to output from a specific line from one file to another.

Comment: That argument syntax has been deprecated for years. `tail -n+2 ...`

Comment: @rici, nothing was changed even with -n+2

Comment: @cynthia: i don't believe tail complains about `+2` not existing if you use ` tail -n+2 input.txt`. *Something* will have changed. What was it?

Comment: @CynthiaGarcia: what version of ubuntu are you using?  And what shell? `echo $SHELL` will tell you.  Also, you can check the `sed` command I just added to the answer.

Comment: @codeforester, 16.01 i guess, it compiles without errors but doesn't print anything there

Comment: @codeforester, Thank you! your last edits works great!